# JNA two dimensional arrays

Tags: java, jna

I try to call a short** in C with JNA.

The C looks like this:

```
void compute(short** in, int row, int col) {
    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < col; j++) {
            printf("in[%d][%d] = %d\n", i,j, in[i][j]);
        }
    }
}
```

- Passing a short[][] from JNA doesn't work.
- The JNA documentation say "To map a native multi-dimensional array, use a single-dimensional Java array" but it doesn't work. When calling

  'nativeLib.compute(new short[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 }, 2, 2);
  I get:  java.lang.Error: Invalid memory access at com.sun.jna.Native.invokeVoid(Native Method)
- It seems that a PointerByReference is needed, I tried to fill the PointerByReference with PointerByReference that contains short values but it doesn't work:

  ```
  Pointer pointerOfArray = new Memory(row * col * Native.getNativeSize(Short.TYPE));
  for(int i=0;i<row;i++) {

      Pointer pointer = new Memory(col * Native.getNativeSize(Short.TYPE));
      for(int j=0;j<col;j++) {
          pointer.setShort(j*Native.getNativeSize(Short.TYPE), in[i][j]);
      }
      pointerOfArray.setPointer(i*row*Native.getNativeSize(Short.TYPE), pointer);
  }
  ```
- I also tried:

  ```
      Pointer pointer = new Memory(4*Short.SIZE);

  Pointer pointer1 = new Memory(2*Short.SIZE);
  pointer1.setShort(0,(short)1);
  pointer1.setShort(Short.SIZE,(short)2);

  Pointer pointer2 = new Memory(2*Short.SIZE);
  pointer2.setShort(0,(short)3);
  pointer2.setShort(Short.SIZE,(short)4);

  pointer.setPointer(0, pointer1);
  pointer.setPointer(2*Short.SIZE, pointer2);

  nativeLib.compute(new PointerByReference(pointer), 2,2);
  ```

But I get `in[0][0] = 3184
in[0][1] = 10460
in[1][0] = 3344
in[1][1] = 10460`

Does anyone have an idea? I can't change the C signature, I have to deal with this short**

Thanks a lot.

**Solution**

I finnaly succed! doing this:

```
        short[][] in = {
            {1,2,3},
            {4,5,6},
    };

    Pointer[] data = new Pointer[in.length];
    for(int i=0;i<in.length;i++) {
        data[i] = new Memory(2*Short.SIZE);
        data[i].write(0, in[i], 0,in[0].length);
    }

    nativeLib.compute(data, in.length,in[0].length);
```

With result:

```
in[0][0] = 1
in[0][1] = 2
in[0][2] = 3
in[1][0] = 4
in[1][1] = 5
in[1][2] = 6
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Glad to see the "array of pointers" version worked for you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JNA only handles single dimension arrays.

And, technically, so does C.  A `short *` could be a 1d, 2d, or 3d array.  You wouldn't know unless you knew the internals.  Only by reading documentation do you know that the function is expecting a 2D array.  All you're really doing is passing a pointer to the first element of the array (total length row*col), and then use (rowIndex * col + colIndex) to fetch the result.  In JNA you'd just use a 1D array to match.

In this case, however, you have a `short **` so you know you have a 1D array of pointers, each pointer pointing to a 1D array of `short`s.  In JNA, you create an array of pointers (`Pointer[]`) for the first *; each will point to the first "column" of a new row (the second *).

The `Invalid Memory Access` error indicates you have not properly allocated the Native memory, and gives you a strong hint at the answer:  you cannot simply pass a primitive array as a parameter.   You must allocate its memory, either by using the `Memory` class or by including the array as part of a `Structure`.

The `new short[] {1, 2, 3, 4}` doesn't work here, because you haven't allocated native-side memory to support the java memory for that array.  You were on the right track with that memory allocation you did by using the `Memory` class.

In C, the `short** in` is expecting an array of pointers.  So you should start out by declaring an array of pointers:

```
Pointer[] p = new Pointer[row];
```

Then you'll set the pointers for each row, allocating memory:

```
p[0] = new Memory(col * Native.getNativeSize(Short.TYPE));
p[1] = new Memory(col * Native.getNativeSize(Short.TYPE));
```

Now, you can write your array values.  You could iterate over the columns with offset and `setShort()` but you can also write directly using [Pointer.write()](http://java-native-access.github.io/jna/4.3.0/javadoc/com/sun/jna/Pointer.html#write-long-short:A-int-int-) e.g.,

```
p[0].write(0, new short[] {1, 2}, 0, 2);
p[1].write(0, new short[] {3, 4}, 0, 2);
```

Then you would pass `p` to the native C for `in`.

Comment: About the first solution, call 'nativeLib.compute(new short[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 }, 2, 2);' gives a ; "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Invalid memory access
 at com.sun.jna.Native.invokeVoid(Native Method)"

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help it's almose ok, but with both updated solutions the result is: `in[0][0] = 1
in[0][1] = 2
in[1][0] = 3200
in[1][1] = 10525`